# How can I validate Ext.form.DateField using min/maxValue, without using time?

Tags: validation, javascript-framework, extjs, datefield

I'm having the following problem: I want to validate a DateField so that it has a value between the minValue / maxValue range. (greater or equal, lower or equal)

The problem is that I think the framework takes the time in milliseconds.

I've tried using a custom vtype such as:

```
Ext.apply(Ext.form.VTypes,{
dates: function(val, field){
    try{
        if(this.disabled){
            return true;
        }

        if(Ext.value(val,null,false)==null){
            this.datesText = "This field is required.";
            return this.allowBlank; //the text message won't be shown in case blank is allowed.
        }

        if(Ext.value(field.minValue,null,false)!=null){
            if(Ext.util.Format.date(val,"Ymd")<Ext.util.Format.date(field.minValue,"Ymd")){
                this.datesText = "The value is invalid.<br/>";
                this.datesText = "it must be greater or equal than " + field.minValue;
                return false;
            }
        }

        if(Ext.value(field.maxValue,null,false)!=null){
            if(Ext.util.Format.date(val,"Ymd")>Ext.util.Format.date(field.maxValue,"Ymd")){
                this.datesText = "The value is invalid.<br/>";
                this.datesText = "It must be lower or equal than " + field.maxValue;
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;

    }catch(e){
        return false;
    }
},
datesText: 'The value is invalid.', //error message
datesMask: / /  //regexp to filter the characters allowed
```

});

Basically what it does is convert the values to a '**Ymd**' format and then compare values as numbers.

If I debug this code, the validation goes okay, but for some reason I still get an error message. I believe the framework is trying to validate the field again after my validation.

Thank you!

Sebastián

Answer (score 1):

```
minValue : Date/String
```

The minimum allowed date. Can be either a Javascript date object or a string date in a valid format (defaults to null).

```
maxValue : Date/String
```

The maximum allowed date. Can be either a Javascript date object or a string date in a valid format (defaults to null).

and in case you needed to disable some dates

```
disabledDates : Array
```

An array of "dates" to disable, as strings. These strings will be used to build a dynamic regular expression so they are very powerful. Some examples:
// disable these exact dates:

```
disabledDates: ["03/08/2003", "09/16/2003"]
```

// disable these days for every year:

```
disabledDates: ["03/08", "09/16"]
```

// only match the beginning (useful if you are using short years):

```
disabledDates: ["^03/08"]
```

// disable every day in March 2006:

```
disabledDates: ["03/../2006"]
```

// disable every day in every March:

```
disabledDates: ["^03"]
```

Comment: Hey Antonio, sorry but I don't want to use the disabledDates property. I just want the framework to validate my Field using dates in the format Ymd, while the framework does this:  /*if (this.minValue && time < this.minValue.clearTime().getTime()) {*/

Comment: I'm trying to avoid overriding the "getErrors" method (http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/source/DateField.html#method-Ext.form.DateField-getErrors) and use a custom validation.

Comment: have you tried the validationDelay property,default is 250ms.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of fixed dates mentioned above, use this:

```
//doesn't allow past today
maxValue: new Date() 
//Only allows 7 days in the past from current date.
minValue: Ext.Date.add(new Date(), Ext.Date.DAY, -7)
```